# Ansible error using `win_copy`: "Unexpected failure during module execution"

Tags: deployment, ansible, ansible-2.x

I upgraded to Python 3.5 and Ansible deployment started failing, not sure if they are related, but here is the info:

> Ansible version: 2.3.2

`yaml` file:

```
  - name: Collect compiled DLLs for publishing
    win_copy:
      src: '{{ download_dir }}/tmp/xxxx/bin/Release/PublishOutput/bin/'
      dest: '{{ work_dir }}\bin'
```

Error:

```
{
  "failed": true,
  "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
  "stdout": ""
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to Ansible 2.5.1 to fix this issue.

Summary from the [pull request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/37964):

> When `win_copy` copies multiple files it can sometimes delete the local `tmp` folder that should be used by multiple modules. This means any further modules that need to access this local `tmp` folder will fail.
>
> We never came across this in ansible-test as we ran a Python module on localhost which causes the ansiballz cache to stop `win_copy` from successfully deleting this folder.